# Find directional derivative of $f(x,y)= \sqrt[3]{x^3-y^3}$ in direction of vector $u= (1,2)$ at point $(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Here's my attempt:
$$f_x (0,0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}h=1$$ 
$$f_y (0,0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(0,h)-f(0,0)}h=1$$

$D_\hat u f(0,0)= f_x(0,0)*(1/\sqrt5)+f_y(0,0)*(2/\sqrt5)$

$=3/\sqrt5$

Is this correct?
Do I have to satisfy the $C^1$ class here? Since the partial derivative is not continuous at $(0,0)$ maybe it is not satisfied.

Comment: Your computation of the directional derivative at $(0,0)$ in the direction $(0,1)$ is incorrect. Where is the $\sqrt{5}$ coming from?

Comment: isn't the direction (1,2)? the square root of 5 comes from the unit vector  u/||u||

Comment: It is. Where did the $\sqrt{5}$ come from?

Comment: Why are you normalising the direction??? Look at the definition of directional derivative?

Comment: Is u already normalised? I'm just copying the method used in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qAPnUIrLqg&t=174s

Comment: The directional derivative is defined as $df(x,h) = \lim_{t \to 0} {f(x+th) -f(x) \over t}$.

Comment: OP is probably using a definition of directional derivative where the direction vector has to be a **unit** vector. Some discussion on this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative#Restriction_to_a_unit_vector and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative#Using_only_direction_of_vector.

Comment: I noticed you (also) deleted this question just after receiving an answer. **Don't do that.**

Answer (score 1):

Just compute it directly.
$df((0,0),(1,2)) = \lim_{t \to 0} { f(t,2t)-f(0,0) \over t} = \lim_{t \to 0} {\sqrt[3]{t^3-8t^3}-0 \over t}=-\sqrt[3]{7}$.